# Displaying error message once in foreach loop

Tags: php, html, foreach

i had a simple input field using propel to change values in a database. The error was displayed on the bottom of the form with what was wrong. Now i wan't the error to be displayed behind the correct input field. The problem with that is that the input fields are build dynamicly using a foreach loop. So when i wan't to show the error on the front-end it shows it after every input field with the same name. In this case i have 3 fields with 'afsluitkosten' if i have a error for changing only one i wan't it to show only after the matching input field.

```
if (isset($_POST['opslaan'])) {

    $naam = $_POST['naam'];
    $afsluitkosten = $_POST['afsluitkosten'];
    $percentage = $_POST['percentage'];
    $btw = $_POST['btw'];
    $id = $_POST['opslaan'];
    if ($afsluitkosten < 15)
     {
        if ($percentage < 1)
         {
            if ($btw < 50)
             {
                $annuleringOpslaan = AnnuleringsverzekeringQuery::create()->findOneById($id);
                $annuleringOpslaan->setNaam($naam);
                $annuleringOpslaan->setAfsluitkosten($afsluitkosten);
                $annuleringOpslaan->setPercentage($percentage);
                $annuleringOpslaan->setBtw($btw);
                $annuleringOpslaan->save();

                $opslaanSucces = "Annuleringsverzekering $naam is opgeslagen";
            } else {
                $fout1 = "De btw van annuleringsverzekering $naam moet onder de 50 zitten";
            }
        } else {
            $fout2 = "De percentage van annuleringsverzekering $naam moet onder de 1 zitten";
        }
    } else {
        $fout3 = "De afsluitkosten van annuleringsverzekering $naam moet onder de 15 zitten";
    }
};

// Gegevens ophalen en laten zien in front end
$annuleringen = AnnuleringsverzekeringQuery::create()
    ->find();

$annuleringarray = array();


foreach ($annuleringen as $annulering) {
    $array["id"] = $annulering->getId();
    $array["naam"] = $annulering->getNaam();
    $array["afsluitkosten"] = $annulering->getAfsluitkosten();
    $array["percentage"] = $annulering->getPercentage();
    $array["btw"] = $annulering->getBtw();
    $array["fout1"] = $fout1;
    $array["fout2"] = $fout2;
    $array["fout3"] = $fout3;

    array_push($annuleringarray, $array);
};
```

This is the html

````
    <h2>{$doctitle}</h2>

    {foreach $annuleringarray as $array}
    <form action="annuleringsverzekering_bewerken.php" method="post">

        <label for="naam">Naam</label><input name="naam" value="{$array.naam}"><br>
        <label for="afsluitkosten">Afsluitkosten</label><input name="afsluitkosten" value="{$array.afsluitkosten}"><span class="error">{$array.fout3}</span><br>
        <label for="percentage">Percentage</label><input name="percentage" value="{$array.percentage}"><span class="error">{$array.fout2}</span><br>
        <label for="btw">Btw</label><input name="btw" value="{$array.btw}"><span class="error">{$array.fout1}</span> <br> 
        <button name="opslaan" value={$array.id}>Opslaan</button> <br> <br>

    </form>
    {/foreach}

    <h3 style="color:green;">{$opslaanSucces}</h3>

</body> ```
````

Answer (score 1):

```
$errors=array(); // on before `if (isset($_POST['opslaan'])) {`
```

And errors like following passing error to array:

```
$errors[] = "Annuleringsverzekering $naam is opgeslagen";
```

and displaying:

```
if ($errors){
 foreach($errors as $error){
 //do what ever you want here `echo $error;` or not echo $error;
 }
}
```

if you want to show errors below to input having error then check this example:
https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-crud-application.php